# Rails: Best way to group and display a association with 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 model: Place, Service, ItemService and ItemServicesProduction.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_services, through: :place_item_services
  has_many :place_item_services
end


class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: item_services
end


class ItemService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
end
```

I want to show place with item_services group by Service.
example.

Table place_item_services

```
+----+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | place_id | item_service_id  | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        5 |                1 | 2016-05-16 12:31:59 | 2016-05-16 12:31:59 |
|  2 |        5 |                2 | 2016-05-16 12:31:59 | 2016-05-16 12:31:59 |
|  3 |        6 |                2 | 2016-05-21 07:58:19 | 2016-05-21 07:58:19 |
|  4 |        5 |                5 | 2016-06-02 08:32:24 | 2016-06-02 08:32:24 |
|  5 |        5 |                6 | 2016-06-02 08:32:24 | 2016-06-02 08:32:24 |
+----+----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

table Service

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | service 1 |
|  2 | service 2 |
+----+-----------+
```

table item_services

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | name  | facility_id |
+----+-------+-------------+
|  1 | sv1-1 |           1 |
|  2 | sv1-2 |           1 |
|  3 | sv1-3 |           1 |
|  4 | sv2-1 |           2 |
|  5 | sv2-2 |           2 |
|  6 | sv2-3 |           2 |
+----+------ +-------------+
```

When i show place in View (with place id = 5)
i want to display

```
Place_Name
/*Service is here*/

 1. service 1
    - sv1-1
    - sv1-2
 2. service 2
    - sv2-2
    - sv2-3
```

The best way how to display same above? (can use inclues, joins, group by .etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your controller**

```
@place    = Place.find(5)
@services = Services.includes({item_services: :place_item_services}).where(place_item_services: {place_id: @place.id})
```

**your view**

```
<p>Place: <%= @place.name %></p>
<ol>
  <% @services.each do |service| %>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <% service.item_services.each do |item_service| %>
          <li><%= item_service.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: cám ơn a :D.
cho e hỏi là tại sao khi e puts số lượng `service.item_services.count` thì nó ra =3. mà each chỉ lặp có 2 lần là sao a? 
e ko hiểu chỗ này lắm ?

Comment: It's weird mate! Perhaps your `item_service.name` is nil?